# How to verify windowing is working in Apache Beam Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have **dataflow job using apache beam** fix window of 1 min. It consume messages from pub sub topic and sinks to BigQuery table. 
Even after using windowing for 1 min , I can see messages are getting sinked to BQ as soon as those are published by consumer.
Is there way I can confirm that windowing is actually working? I have seen many examples but none of the article is mentioning about validations.

Comment: Did you check the timestamps of data written to BQ? whether they are within the expected window or not?

Comment: I have eventTime coming from the producer and my job adding ingestion time. In BQ I can see only miliseconds difference between two. For eg eventTime is 2023-06-14T19:47:49.488Z then ingestionTime is 2023-06-14T19:47:49.891Z.
My expectation is for some records it should come around more than 1 min or higher

Comment: Can you share your window code? it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were not able to set the proper triggers and used the default configuration which is event time. I believe you should use the After Processing Time trigger and set it to a minute like this code from the [official docs](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#triggers)

```
pcollection | WindowInto(
    FixedWindows(1 * 60),
    trigger=AfterProcessingTime(1 * 60),
    accumulation_mode=AccumulationMode.DISCARDING)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own [Test pipeline](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/pipelines/test-your-pipeline/#an-example-test-for-a-composite-transform) using something like:

```java
Pipeline p = TestPipeline.create();
```

For **testing unbounded pipelines**, there's a [blog post](https://beam.apache.org/blog/test-stream/) that explains how to do it, it may have change a bit since 2016, but you'll find some good resources to start.

Your goal is to use `PAssert` to verify that tests are passing in the different `PCollection` triggered by your windows.

```java
// Only one value is emitted for the blue team
PAssert.that(teamScores)
       .inWindow(window)
       .containsInAnyOrder(KV.of("blue", 18));
p.run();
```